# How do I use Ninject BindUsingRegex

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ninject-extensions

How do I use Ninject BindUsingRegex from Ninject.Extension.Convention i.e.

if I want to do the below

`kernel.Bind<Interface<OfThisType>>().To<OfThisTypeThing>();`
`kernel.Bind<Interface<OfThisOtherType>>().To<OfThisOtherTypeThing>();`
...

using BindUsingRegex? Or am I missing a better way of doing this without just adding an explicit declaration for each new instance